# how can i improve the efficency by key look up and table scan in my query in sql server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

How can I target the key's by seeing the execute plan when key lookup comes in the query? I am not sure exactly which particular key to target in the table by seeing the seek predicates, kindly help me out on this

Here below I have pasted my query execution plan (key lookup)

[image]

Please find the query which I am using

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), CTC_VALUE_DATE, 12) AS CTC_VALUE_DATES ,  
   MCURR.CURRENCY_CODE, 
   FTS_CUSTOMER_TRAN_CONTROL.*,
   MCURR.* 
FROM 
   FTS_CUSTOMER_TRAN_CONTROL 
INNER JOIN 
   @TEMPTABLE TEMP ON FTS_CUSTOMER_TRAN_CONTROL.CTC_PACKAGE_ID = TEMP.PACKAGEID
LEFT JOIN 
   MASTER_CURRENCY AS MCURR ON MCURR.CURRENCY_ID = FTS_CUSTOMER_TRAN_CONTROL.CTC_CURR_CODE    
WHERE 
   CTC_GEN_REFID = @REFIDS
```

Comment: If you do a `SELECT *` then SQL Server will have to go to the actual table data (using the expensive `Key Lookup`) since you're requesting **all columns**. There's not much you can do about that - other than **not** using `SELECT *` and instead specifying a small list of columns that you actually need.

Comment: Do you really need * from both tables? That is probably the cause of the key lookup. Why don't you re-write the query so that you're only pulling the columns that you need? Then you can optimize the index for that...

Comment: Also: `Table Scan` indicates you don't have a clustered index on that table. That's bad - you should **always** have a **good** clustered index (e.g. on a `INT IDENTITY` column) in your "real" data tables.

Comment: @marc_s thank you i will follow your tips by calling needed columns and using clustered index, other than to improve do i need perform any things by seeing predicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to avoid the KEY LOOKUP then you will have to select only the columns you required and also try to create the covering index on te columns you use in select.